# Is it right to use React.memo properly?

Tags: reactjs

i want to know how can i use React.memo, useMemo and useCallback correct way.

I know if dependency or props have object and array, it doesnt work properly.

So I'm trying to apply it to my project as small as possible because I have a lot of object and array type props and dependency

```js
// email is props
const onRequestOTP: () => void = useCallback(async () => {
    const res = await resendEmail(email);
    if (res?.data?.status === 1) {
      setIsResponseError(false);
      setIsRequest(true);
      setStep(2);
    } else if (res?.data?.status === 0) {
      setIsResponseError(true);
    }
  }, [email]);
```

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { memo } from 'react';
// lib
import { selectpalette } from 'lib/styles/palette';
// components
import Font from 'components/atoms/Font';
// @mui
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import MdiIcon from 'components/atoms/Icon';

const Alert: ({ text, isError }: Props) => JSX.Element = ({ text, isError }: Props) => {
  const bgColor = isError ? 'red_op_12' : 'primary_op_12';

  return (
    <Wrapper bgColor={selectpalette(bgColor)}>
      <Grid
        container
        alignItems="center"
        direction="row"
        flexWrap="nowrap"
        justifyContent="space-between"
      >
        <Grid item sx={{ paddingRight: '8px' }}>
          {isError ? (
            <MdiIcon width={20} height={20} src="/icons/warning/ic_warning_red_round.svg" />
          ) : (
            <MdiIcon width={20} height={20} src="/icons/mail/ic_mail_primary.svg" />
          )}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item flex="1 1 auto">
          <Font className="body-1" color={isError ? 'error' : 'primary'}>
            {text}
          </Font>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = styled.div<{ bgColor: string }>`
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ${props => props.bgColor};
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;

interface Props {
  text: string;
  isError: boolean;
}

export default memo(Alert);
```

```js
  const FormControlSX = useMemo(
    () => ({
      width: '100%',
      '& .MuiFilledInput-root': {
        borderTopLeftRadius: '8px',
        borderTopRightRadius: '8px',
        backgroundColor: palette.white,
      },
    }),
    [],
  );
```

Let me know there is an incorrect use.

Answer (score 0):

All three are related to optimization. If you don't have a performance issues then don't use them. If you have — measure first.

- The `Alert` component is a single and not heavy (I guess) so using `memo` doesn't improve a performance
- `useCallback` is rarely used. For example, if you use `onRequestOTP` as prop for a lot of children (or one heavy child) and want to prevent rerendering you can use `useCallback` in conjunction with `memo` for a child component
- The function inside `useMemo` is cheap so nothing to do here